# UItextfield doesn't work in custom UIView

Tags: objective-c

This is my issue:

I have a class that extends from `UIView` and I have called `VerticalFieldLayout`.

**FieldLayoutHeader:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Layout.h"

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
static int const VIEW_SPACE = 5;
extern int HORIZONTAL_LAYOUT;
extern int VERTICAL_LAYOUT;

@interface FieldLayout : UIView <Layout> {
    @private
    float xPos;
    float yPos;
    int type;
}
@property(nonatomic) int type;

-(void) applyRadius: (float) radius;
@end
```

**Field Layout Implementation**

```
#import "FieldLayout.h"

int HORIZONTAL_LAYOUT = 345678;
int VERTICAL_LAYOUT = 12345;

@implementation FieldLayout
@synthesize type;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        xPos = 0;
        yPos = 0;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)resize:(CGRect)movement {
    float cwidth = self.frame.size.width;
    float cheight = self.frame.size.height;

    if (type == HORIZONTAL_LAYOUT) {
        if (cwidth < movement.size.width + movement.origin.x) {
            cwidth = movement.size.width + movement.origin.x;
        }
    }

    if (type == VERTICAL_LAYOUT) {
        if (cheight < movement.size.width + movement.origin.y) {
            cheight = movement.size.height + movement.origin.y;
        }
    }

    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, cwidth, cheight);
}

- (void)applyRadius:(float)radius {
    [[self layer] setCornerRadius:radius];
    [[self layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
}

- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view {
    if (type == HORIZONTAL_LAYOUT) {
        view.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view    .frame.size.height);

        xPos = xPos + view.frame.size.width + VIEW_SPACE;
    } else {
        view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, yPos, view.frame.size.width,     view.frame.size.height);

        yPos = yPos + view.frame.size.height + VIEW_SPACE;
    }

    [self resize:view.frame];

    [super addSubview:view];
}


@end
```

**VerticalHeader:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FieldLayout.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface VerticalFieldLayout : FieldLayout
    - (void)setBorderNcolor:(float)width andcolor:(UIColor *)andcolor;
@end
```

**VerticalImplementation:**

```
#import "VerticalFieldLayout.h"

@implementation VerticalFieldLayout

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setType:VERTICAL_LAYOUT];

        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)applyRadius:(float)radius {
    [[self layer] setCornerRadius:radius];
}

- (void)setBorderNcolor:(float)width andcolor:(UIColor *) color {
    self.layer.borderWidth = width;
    self.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}
@end
```

Now, I added aprox 4 VerticalLayouts using addSubviews to a VerticalFieldLayout.  In every VerticalFieldLayout (the 4 ones) I added UITexfields.

**The problem:**  Why the tab event not respond when I tab on UITextfields? but if I add the UITextfields directly to the UIViewcontroller's View they work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:

I had to override this method in FieldLayout:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSEnumerator *reverseE = [self.subviews reverseObjectEnumerator];
    UIView *iSubView;

    while ((iSubView = [reverseE nextObject])) {
        UIView *viewWasHit = [iSubView hitTest:[self convertPoint:point toView:iSubView]     withEvent:event];
        if (viewWasHit) {
            return viewWasHit;
        }

    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Now, every SubView respond touch event!